# Multiple input keras neural network model with data generator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, data-generation

I have two images. One for left eye and one for right eye. I want to feed them at once in a neural network.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
XL_train, XL_val, yL_train, yL_val = train_test_split(XL, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
XR_train, XR_val, yR_train, yR_val = train_test_split(XR, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

XL contain image of left eye  `(3500, 224, 224, 3)`
XR contain images of right eye `(3500, 224, 224, 3)`

I have create the data generator and transform my image as follows

```
XR_generator = train_datagen.flow(XR_train, yR_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
XL_generator = train_datagen.flow(XL_train, yL_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
vR_generator = val_datagen.flow(XR_val, yR_val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
vL_generator = val_datagen.flow(XL_val, yL_val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Use resnet as model

```
import keras
left_input=Input(shape=XL.shape[1::])
right_input=Input(shape=XR.shape[1::])

left_model = ResNet50(include_top=False,input_tensor=left_input)
for layer in left_model.layers:
        layer.name = layer.name + '_left'
        layer.trainable = True


right_model = ResNet50(include_top=False,input_tensor=right_input)
for layer in right_model.layers:
        layer.name = layer.name + '_right'
        layer.trainable = True
```

Layer attached with resnet

```
x = keras.layers.concatenate([left_model.output, right_model.output])
x=  keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(512)(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(512)(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Activation('relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
out = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=out)
```

Compile the model and fit the model as follows

```
history=model.fit_generator(generator=[XL_generator,XR_generator],
                        steps_per_epoch=steps_train,
                        validation_data=[vL_generator,vR_generator],
                        validation_steps=steps_valid,
                        epochs=10,
                        )
```

I am getting following error.
AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'ndim'

## Update

```
def multi_train_gen(gen,XR_train,XL_train,yR_train,yL_train):
  XR_generator = train_datagen.flow(XR_train, yR_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  XL_generator = train_datagen.flow(XL_train, yL_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  while True:
    X1i = XR_generator.next()
    X2i = XL_generator.next()
    yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1] 

def multi_val_gen(gen,XR_val,XL_val,yR_val,yL_val):
  vR_generator = val_datagen.flow(XR_val, yR_val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  vL_generator = val_datagen.flow(XL_val, yL_val, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

  while True:
    X1i = vR_generator.next()
    X2i = vL_generator.next()
    yield [X1i[0], X2i[0]], X2i[1]
```

training generator

```
train_gen=multi_train_gen(train_datagen,XR_train,XL_train,yR_train,yL_train)
```

validation generator

```
val_gen=multi_val_gen(val_datagen,XR_val,XL_val,yR_val,yL_val)
```

But problem is not that i am unbale to access classes. I wish i can use classification report from scikit learn

Comment: what's steps_valid?  and modify [vL_generator,vR_generator] to (vL_generator,vR_generator).. and let's see

Comment: You need to change your generator, ```fit_generator``` takes single generator as input not list of generator. This generator should yield batches as ```return [xl_batch,xr_batch], batch_labels```. Refer [this](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit_generator) for more info.

Comment: i have updated the post. but i am unable to access the predicted variable. What i meant i want to get y_true value and y_pred values from this model.